# Lista de tudo que implemente tal classe

Tags: java

Bom eu queria saber por que não posso criar uma lista de classes que implemente outra classe, por exemplo

`public List<Class<? implements Classe>> classes;` isso retorna um erro de sintax...

Mas posso criar uma de classes que estendam de outra classe...

`public List<Class<? extends Classe>> classes;` não retorna nenhum erro...

Comment: Você quer dizer, implemente uma interface, certo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embora a palavra-chave seja a mesma, `extends` numa declaração genérica funciona para ambas classe e interface. Ou seja, você pode sim criar uma lista de tudo que implemente uma interface, da mesma forma que cria uma lista de tudo que herda de uma classe:

```
interface CommandExecutor { }

class Foo implements CommandExecutor { }
class Bar implements CommandExecutor { }

public List<Class<? extends CommandExecutor>> commandExecutos =
    new ArrayList<Class<? extends CommandExecutor>>();
```

[Exemplo no ideone](https://ideone.com/l6ZF20) ([mesmo exemplo com classes](https://ideone.com/mSZ9re)).